# How to accept String letter Input from int conversion in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

I am working on a simple python exercise where I ask a series of questions and get input from the user. I prompt the user with "Enter your age" and I want the program to continue rather than be corrupt if the user enters a letter value for the age rather than int because I am converting to int to figure if the age is less than 18 or greater than and if it is between specific ages. I can't convert letters to an int.

```
age = input("Please enter your age: ")
if int(age) < 18 or int(age) > 120:
    print("We're sorry, you are not old enough to be qualified for our program. We hope to see you in the future.")
    end()
if int(age) > 18 and int(age) < 120:
    print("You are " + age + "years old.")
if int(age) > 120:
    print("You are not qualified for this program. ")
    end()

#Somewhere in this script I am hoping to accept the letter input without sending an error to the program.
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: What should the script do if the age is exactly 18 or 120? None of your conditions match those cases.

Comment: Do the integer conversion just once and assign it to a variable. You can put the exception handling there.

Comment: @Barmar I am still adding different conditions at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try/except.

```
age = input("Please enter your age: ")
try:
    if int(age) < 18 or int(age) > 120:
        print("We're sorry, you are not old enough to be qualified for our program. We hope to see you in the future.")
        end()
    if int(age) > 18 and int(age) < 120:
        print("You are " + age + "years old.")
    if int(age) > 120:
        print("You are not qualified for this program. ")
        end()
except:
    print("Please enter a number")
```

If your int conversion fails the code will jump to except instead of crashing.

If you want the user to retry, you could write something like this instead. Be aware of the ranges you're using and negative numbers.

```
age = input("Please enter your age: ")
ageNum = 0
while(ageNum <= 0):
    try:
        ageNum = int(age)
        if (ageNum) < 18 or ageNum > 120:
            print("We're sorry, you are not old enough to be qualified for our program. We hope to see you in the future.")
            end()
        elif ...
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid number")
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I had learned Try-Except before but I forgot how to work with it.

Comment: Try-except is bad practice because it's inefficient, can cause a variety of scoping bugs, and can disguise other Exceptions which fall under the umbrella. I don't recommend using it in any situation. Instead, use the more Pythonic builtin method `.isnumeric()`

Comment: Try except is pretty standard in python - better to ask forgiveness than permission and all that.  Given the requirement to actually check the value, we need to convert to `int` at some point anyway.  Unless we have good reason to expect malformed data, try except seems more efficient than checking `.isnumeric()` and then calling `int(age)`.  However, I will agree that a bare except clause is dangerous.  Better to explicitly handle `ValueError` and to minimise the try except block (i.e. put all the code using the actual value outside the try except block).

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a while loop, e.g.

```py
while int(age) != age:
    input("Age must be an integer.\nPlease try again.")
```

And as @Barmar stated, you need to check your if statements.

Comment: This would throw an error and terminate the program if the age was not numeric